# Scroll for GUI not working the way I want it to

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scroll

I am trying to get this textarea on this GUI to have a scroll, but when I try to add it either the text area covers the scroll bar or vice versa. No errors. Code:

```java
        // Text Area at the Center
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea ( 16, 58 );
        ta.setEditable ( false ); // set textArea non-editable
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane ( ta );
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent send) {
                String data = tf.getText();
                ta.append("You: " + data + "\n");
                tf.setText("");
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        });
        
        //Adding Components to the frame.
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ta);
        frame.add(ta);
        ta.add(scroll);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I usually `.pack()` my JFrame before I display it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: `ta.add(scroll)` < this is incorrect. You're not supposed to add the `JScrollPane` to the `JTextArea`. The two lines above are also incorrect. Don't add the `JTextArea` to your frame, as the text area is inside the viewport of the `JScrollPane` (since you supplied it to the scrollpanes constructor). The correct approach would be to add `scroll` to your `JFrame`, e.g. `frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scroll)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are the issue:

```java
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, ta);
frame.add(ta);
ta.add(scroll);
```

Don't add the `JTextArea` to your frame, as the `JTextArea` is already correctly configured to be inside the viewport of the `JScrollPane` (since you supplied it to the scrollpanes constructor earlier). Also you're not supposed to add the `JScrollPane` to the `JTextArea`, because you want it the other way around.
The correct approach would be to remove the mentioned lines and to simply add `scroll` to your `JFrame`, like so:

```java
frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Sidenote:

- as mentioned in the comments, consider calling `pack()` on your frame before setting it visible, to size the frame and its components correctly.

Comment: @camickr of course, thanks for the hint, changed it. Copy pasted it from the original snippet and didn't think about it further.